# Convert cURL to Google Apps Script

Tags: http, curl, google-apps-script, github-api

I am trying to convert a cURL command to a Google Apps Script PUT request.
I came up with the below google script but it does not seem to work. When I change the URL of both of these to RequestBin in order to probe what the server side is getting, RequestBin shows that the raw source of both of these come through as exactly the same. Yet, only the cURL command is able to perform the desired action (update a file on github) when I change it back to the github URL.

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Authorization: token yadayda' -d '{"path":"mygeojson.json","message":"Initial Commit","committer":{"name":"Sidd","email":"siddsubra@gmail.com"},"content":"bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=","sha":"0d5a690c8fad5e605a6e8766295d9d459d65de42","branch":"master"}' https://api.github.com/repos/teku45/GeoJSON-Update/contents/mygeojson.json

cURL Command
```

And this is the Google Script

```
function mainscript() {

  var sha = getSHA();
  var authenticationToken = "yadayada";

  var url = "http://api.github.com/repos/teku45/GeoJSON-Update/contents/mygeojson.json";

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "token " + authenticationToken,
  };

  var payload = {  
    "path": "mygeojson.json",
    "message": "Initial Commit",
    "committer":{  
      "name": "Sidd",
      "email": "siddsubra@gmail.com"
    },
    "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=",
    "sha": sha,
    "branch": "master"
  };

  var options = {
    "headers" : headers,
    "method" : "PUT",
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  Logger.log(options);
  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options));
}

Google Apps Script
```

Comment: Can you please share encountered error that appears in the logs? In line with that, I noticed that your GAS `authenticationToken` doesn't match with that of cURL command.

Comment: When authenticating with github have you set scope? If you've just dropped in the [OAuth2 library example](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GitHub.gs) you'll need to add something like `.setScope('repo')` to your service. Without the right scope in your app you'll encounter 404 on create requests

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a script that call a request to a API from scrapy cloud, and had a dificulty to convert curl to App Script request too.

I noticed that payload doesn't worked when i used JSON.stringify, so try remove it from payload:

`"payload" : payload`

Other observation was the need to use Utilities.base64Encode in authentication token:

`headers = {"Authorization":"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(authenticationToken + ":" + "")}`

See this sample:

```
url = "https://app.scrapinghub.com/api/run.json"
  headers = {"Authorization":"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("myToken" + ":" + "")}
  payload = {"project":"327107", "spider":"pmp"}
  options = {"headers":headers, "payload":payload}

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
```